# how to read response cookie using justhttp

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, response

Trying  to get response cookie value using [justhttp](http://justhttp.net)

but always getting nil

```
auth = String(describing: Just.get("https://url.com").cookies["AUTH"]?.value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
auth = Just.get("https://url.com", allowRedirects:false).cookies["AUTH"]!.value
```